# The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility

I have two partitions on my MAC both formatted as Mac OS Extended but only one has macOS on it. When I start the Bootcamp Assistant to install Windows 10 I get the following message:

[image]

How to fix this issue? Do I have to erase the other partition?

Comment: MacBook Pro Mid-2012 using macOS Sierra

Comment: Funny thing is that you could have actually executed step one of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, collaps the second partition into the OSX partition. After that you have one partition.
Then use Bootcamp to Partition/install Windows